# Resample a time series in the frequency domain (FFT)

Tags: r, signal-processing

I'm trying to implement the "synthesis equation" from the [DSP Guide](http://www.dspguide.com/ch8/5.htm), equation 8-2, so I can resample a time series in the frequency domain. The way I read the equation, N is the number of output points, and given the loop of k from 0 to N/2, I can only resample to twice the original sampling rate, at most.

I tried writing a quick implementation in R, but the results are not anything close to what I expect. My code:

```
input <- c(1:9)
nin <- 9
nout <- 17
b <-fft(input)

reals <- Re(b) / (nout / 2)
imags <- Im(b) / (nout / 2)
reals[1] <- reals[1] / 2
reals[(nout/2)] <- reals[(nout/2)] / 2

output <- c(1:nout)
for (i in 1:nout)
{
    realSum <- 0
    imagSum <- 0
    for (k in 1:(nout/2))
    {
        angle <- 2 * pi * (k-1) * (i-1) / nout
        realSum <- realSum + (reals[k] * cos(angle))
        imagSum <- imagSum - (imags[k] * sin(angle))
    }

output[i] <- (realSum + imagSum)
}
```

For my input (sampled at say 1 second, resampling to 0.5 second)

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I get the output

```
[1] -0.7941176  1.5150954  0.7462716  1.5022387  1.6478971  1.8357487  
2.4029773  2.1965426  3.1585254  2.6178195  3.7284660  3.3721128  3.8433588  4.6390705
[15]  3.4699088  6.3005605  2.8175240
```

while my expected output is

```
[1] 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The above code does look like the inverse DFT that you referenced in the article.  From your expected desired input/output, it seems like you need a cheap linear interpolation rather than a DFT/Inverse DFT solution.

From your desired input/output relationship statement above, it seems like you have a desired relationship between a time series input and a desired time series output.

A inverse DFT, which you coded, will go from frequency domain to time domain.

From what I could gather from your statements, start with the series [1,1->9], do a forward DFT (to get to frequency domain), then take that result into an inverse DFT (to get back to time domain).

Hopefully this is a hint in the right direction for you.